# Salt for Aggregations to counter Skew

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to understand the concept of `Salt`-ing to counter `Skew`. Unfortunately, I couldn't find enough information which would help me wrap my head around the concept of Salting in the context of **aggregations** (E.g. `Group By` & `Window` etc) in Spark SQL.

So far I have construed that **salted aggregations** require 2 passes. Hence, I put together the following code snippet that would represent the first pass. However, I am unable to proceed from there on. Can someone please help me proceed with few examples using Spark SQL queries ?

Pass I:

```
create temporary view salt1 
as
select cust, item, cast(rand() * 10 as int) as salt
from tab1;

create temporary view salt2
as
select cust, item
from (select cust, 
             item, 
             row_number() over (partition by salt, cust order by purch) as row_num
     from salt1
     )
where row_num = 1;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110207/spark-how-does-salting-work-in-dealing-with-skewed-data

Comment: I have read this question. However, I want to know how to apply the same thru SQL queries..