# Spark: How do I break up the data located on 1 particular executor?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a large data set that is being shuffle read mostly on a single executor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpi7K.png

I have materialized all previous operations up until the last one: writing to disk.

What I have tried so far is various amount of `df.repartition(n)` but I am not able to break up the hundreds of millions of rows sitting on this single executor.

`sampleBy` I think is the culprit -- I want to sample values of my target class evenly but the distribution is heavily imbalanced. How can I break up the partitions after sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have data skewed problem. you can try adding salt in your operation.

exemple: [spark: How does salting work in dealing with skewed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110207/spark-how-does-salting-work-in-dealing-with-skewed-data)